# jQuery click event not working in IE11 Windows8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Not sure why this wouldn't work, but for some reason, the click event is firing a `console.log` but then it's not executing the `addClass` to the HTML element I'm trying to target. Not sure if there is anything that I need to look out for. I've tested this in Chrome on my Mac and it works fine, but then when I test on a Surface running Windows8, no dice.

Here's what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="window-element">
<p>thing to test</p>
<a href="#" class="close-box">Close this</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".close-box").on('click', function(e){
    $(".window-element").addClass("hidden");
    console.log("click test");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Not sure if there is anything else that I need to work around with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **vanilla JavaScript** for this particular code snippet like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="window-element">
<p>thing to test</p>
<a href="#" class="close-box">Close this</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const closeBox = document.querySelector('.close-box');
const windowElement = document.querySelector('.window-element');

closeBox.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    windowElement.classList.add("hidden");
    console.log("click test");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Check this **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/o6vu0tga/)**.

Comment: `"I would suggest you to use vanilla JavaScript"` - why?

Comment: @user7290573 it seems that it's any issue with IE11 & `eventListeners`. I have checked some workout around online & it seems that doing it with vanilla JavaScript will solve it. Check [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/click-events-not-working-in-ie-11). Let me know if it works...

Comment: jQuery is specifically designed to be cross-platform compliant. The event handler is not the issue

Comment: I figured it out. Looks like there was something that was problematic with another script (WordPress plugin) that was throwing errors and killing the rest of the scripts on the page in IE11. Kicked off the plugin and, BOOM, stuff started working again. I would like to point out that going the vanilla JS route seems like the "safer" bet, but my original jQuery also worked as well. Thanks!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right, but it also depends of the jQuery version the OP is using. Sometimes, there are bugs depending of the jQuery version or browser. For example, this is a [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4370) I found in the recent version of jQuery which has been solved yet. It's unrelated to this issue, but it shows that sometimes there are browser inconsistencies. That's why I suggest it doing it in vanilla js to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To make as a minimum change as possible I would change your JS to:

```
$(document).on('click','.close-box', function(e){
    $('.window-element').addClass('hidden');
    console.log("click test");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This seemed to work for me. Try out this jsfiddle to see if this is what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/91myczwj/1/